# If two digits are the same 0s then make 0 condition in C++ and Root

Tags: c++, c, root-framework

In my code, legends are running within a loop, and I am trying to show a graph with

```
0-10%
10-20%
```

and so on. The problem is when I write this code

```
legend->AddEntry(gr[i], Form("%d0-%d0 %%",i+0,i+1), "lep");
```

It shows

```
00-10%
10-20% etc
```

So how to not show 00, but 0 in the first line?

Comment: C and C++ are very different languages, and in general you should only tag the language you are writing/compiling.

Comment: Is `root` related to [CERN library](https://root.cern/manual/math/)? I guess we need a new tag for that (which nobody will ever find)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen seems there is a tag already - #root-framework

Comment: Did the provided answer help you? If it helped you in some way, consider upvoting it. If it solved your issue, consider accepting it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A small adaptation of the shown statement should be enough; use:

```
legend->AddEntry(gr[i], Form("%d-%d %%", i*10 , (i+1)*10), "lep");
```

**Explanation:**

`Form("%d0-%d0 %%",i+0,i+1)` seems to be some kind of string formatting, and `i` your loop variable which runs from 0 to 9, right? The shown `Form` statement just appends "0" hard-coded to the single digit in `i`; instead, you can multiply i by 10, resulting in the actual numbers you want printed; and since 10*0 is still 0, this will be a single digit still; so, replace the previous Form(...) call with `Form("%d-%d %%", i*10, (i+1)*10)` and you should have the result you want!

In case you're worrying that printing `i*10` is "less efficient" than printing i with "0" suffix - don't. The formatting and output of the string is most probably orders of magnitude slower than the multiplication anyway, so any overhead of doing multiple multiplications is negligible.